# MATLAB Matrix construction advice

Tags: matlab

I need to use MATLAB to solve the following matrix equation:

[image: Matrix Equation]

This matrix is nxn, and I can construct most of the matrix using the following MATLAB code:

```
e = ones(n,1);
A = h^(-2)*spdiags([e (h^2 - 2)*e e], [-1 0 1], n, n);
```

What's a good way to change the first and last row?  Perhaps it would be nice to just add a nice matrix B with the first row as [ 2/h 1/h^2 0 ... 0 0 0 ] and the last row as [ 0 0 0 ... 0 1/h^2 (2h + 1)/h^2] and just take A + B.  How would you do this though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest way is best in this case as you aren't modifying much of the matrix you have created:

```
A(1,:)=A(1,:)+[2/h 1/h^2 zeros(1,n-2)];
A(n,:)=A(n,:)+[zeros(1,n-2) 1/h^2 2/h];
```

or even replace individual elements rather than rows.

Comment: Oh, this method looks promising.  Thanks for the help! :)